# Accessing the properties of a class which contains a property of another class

Tags: c#

```
public class Customer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Person CustPerson { get; set; }
    public Customer()
    {
        this.CustPerson = new Person();
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Customer> CustomerList=new List<Customer>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
    {
        Customer cust = new Customer();
        cust.id = i;
        cust.CustPerson.FirstName = "john" + i.ToString();
        cust.CustPerson.LastName = "deo" + i.ToString();
        cust.CustPerson.Age = 20 + i;
        CustomerList.Add(cust);
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = CustomerList;
}
```

I want `firstname`, `lastname` & `age` to be printed in the `gridview`, but I am getting a single column, instead of three, which contains `mynamespace.person` :-(

Help me out guys... any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's often said that we should prefer composition over inheritance, but in this (classic) case, since a customer presumably *is* a person, perhaps you should change your approach and have `Customer` derive from `Person`, rather than have a `Person` property.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to select the `CustPerson` property (Linq):

```
CustomerList.Add(cust.Select(c => c.CustPerson).ToArray());
```

Also make sure that the `GridView` has `AutoGenerateColumns` set to true.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the process described [here](http://www.dotnetjohn.com/articles.aspx?articleid=219) you can set up the columns for your GridView to display whatever information you like

```
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="CustPerson.FirstName">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerFirstName" runat="server" Text=''<%# ((Person)Eval("CustPerson")).Firstname %>''></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="CustPerson.LastName">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerLastName" runat="server" Text=''<%# ((Person)Eval("CustPerson")).LastName %>''></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age" SortExpression="CustPerson.Age">
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="lblCustomerAge" runat="server" Text=''<%# ((Person)Eval("CustPerson")).Age %>''></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Column;
    CheckBox checkbox;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Customer> CustomerList = new List<Customer>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            Customer cust = new Customer();
            cust.id = i;                 
            cust.FirstName = "john" + i.ToString();
            cust.LastName = "deo" + i.ToString();
            cust.Age = 20 + i;
            CustomerList.Add(cust);
        }
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = CustomerList;            
    }
}
public class Customer:Person
{
    public int id { get; set; }       
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for ur help friends..found an easy way  to do it..i just kept person as my base class for customer..so that i can set the properties of base class properties with derived class object and i finally add customer object to list...